# מָחֹה אֶמְחֶה Remez

Tags: riddle, beshalach

כִּי מָחֹה אֶמְחֶה אֶת זֵכֶר עֲמָלֵק

What  does אֶמְחֶה stand for?

Hint: See Yalkut Reuvani or the Gra or the Chidah for amazing Remez

Comment: You can ask what the infinitive מָחֹה adds, but the verb אֶמְחֶה is necessary for meaning of the _pasuk_ and not extra.

Comment: I remember in elementary school, we took the "Iowa Test of Basic Skills" at one point. One of my classmates, to the amusement of the rest, raised his hand and asked "What does Iowa stand for?"

Comment: CLEARLY A RIDDLE!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weekly "Torah Lodaas" sheet (by Rabbi Matis Blum zt'l of Queens, New York) for *B'shalach* 5771, quotes the book *Gan Yosef*, by the author of *Pardes Yosef*, as saying that the duplication is to indicate that although after erasing a mark is still visible, the erasure of *Amalek* must be even of that mark.

Answer (score 0):

אמחה is the essential for Fighting amalek and winning which Happened three times lets see each case: The first is our Parsha Beshalach we had our main characters Involved
Where

**אמחה**

אהרן
משה
חור
השם

**אמחה**

אסתר
מרדכי
חרבונה
השם

**אמחה**

אליהו(1

2)משיח

3) 'ח

```
נסיכים(see: ב amud סוכה נב)
```

4)השם

Comment: Good stuff I think I hear Rabbi Reisman say this in his MLK day Hakel Missing thelast part